# Query across multiple schemas, unknown until execution time

Tags: postgresql, schema, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have multiple schemas that I need to query across. The schemas are not known in advance, for example:

- U111
- U222
- U333

I need to select across these three schemas from a specific table in each of these schemas. Can I put this query across these three schemas? If so, how can I query across them? Remember, I will not know the schema names ahead of time, so they will need to be built dynamically.

Comment: You could write down a function that will query the pg_namespace table (which contains all the schemas in the DB) and then run the query against every table in the schema if exists.

Comment: Fabrizio, thank you for your respone. Is there is a way to accomplish this in a view instead of a function?

Comment: Is the table in all the schemas exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, all schemas will have the exact same tables with each table structured exactly the same.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL - PL/PgSQL with `EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 11):

If you just need results from multiple schemas, you can re-use the same query string and set the `search_path` in between:

```
SET search_path = u111, public;
SELECT * FROM foo;
SET search_path = u222, public;
SELECT * FROM foo;
...
```

The schema search path [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) in Postgres works much like the search path a file system. Related:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)
- [PostgreSQL and default Schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40488/postgresql-and-default-schemas/40517#40517)

If you need to combine results from multiple schemas (probably your use-case), you can either build the statement in your client or use a [plpgsql function with dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). That's what I would do. Plain SQL does not allow parametrized identifiers (schema, table, column, ...).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_schemas text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (bar int, baz text) AS  -- matching return type
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT string_agg(format('SELECT bar, baz FROM %I.foo', sch)  -- your query here
                          , E'\nUNION ALL\n')
   FROM   unnest(_schemas) sch
   );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Builds and executes a query of the following form dynamically:

```
SELECT bar, baz FROM u111.foo
UNION ALL
SELECT bar, baz FROM u222.foo
UNION ALL
SELECT bar, baz FROM u333.foo;
```

Schema names are escaped as identifiers properly to defend against SQL injection.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=64189f4e4caa160716235fe765786677)* (returning query string as error msg instead of executing it)
Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c18ec/1)

Answer (score 1):

If your table structures are the same, you could use table inheritance then create a master schema with all the table structures and have the others inherit table from that one: 
Here is an article we wrote describing the technique:

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/59-How-to-Inherit,-Unherit-and-Merge-Inherit.html