# How do I create an insert-only user for a Postgres table with an index?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema

Here's my proposed schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Surveys (
    id serial primary key,
    user_email citext,
    survey_data jsonb,
    created_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);
CREATE INDEX surveys_email_idx ON Surveys(user_email);

CREATE USER SurveyWriter;
```

I know I need to:

```sql
GRANT INSERT ON dbname.Surveys TO SurveyWriter;
```

But do I also need to:

```sql
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON dbname.surveys_email_idx to SurveyWriter;
```

Is there anything else I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) on an *index*. Indexes do not have separate permissions, they are "implementations details" of the owning table.

You already covered the `INSERT` privilege (as table owner or superuser):

```
GRANT INSERT ON dbname.surveys TO SurveyWriter;
```

If you want the role to log in, it needs access to the database.

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_database TO SurveyWriter;
```

Plus, the role needs the [`LOGIN` privilege](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html). `CREATE USER` does that implicitly. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html)

> `CREATE USER` is now an alias for `CREATE ROLE`. The only difference
> is that when the command is spelled `CREATE USER`, `LOGIN` is assumed
> by default, [...]

And access in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

(Else you might want to use [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html) instead.)

You need at least `USAGE` on the schema - which is given by default in the `public` schema, unless you revoked it. The schema in your example has the (misleading!) name "dbname". So:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dbname TO SurveyWriter;
```

You are not confusing databases and schemas, are you? See:

- [PostgreSQL and default Schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40488/postgresql-and-default-schemas/40517#40517)

Since you use a `serial`, you also need at least `USAGE` on the connected `SEQUENCE`:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE public.surveys_id_seq TO SurveyWriter;
```

Or consider an `IDENTITY` column instead, where no separate privileges are required. Requires Postgres 10 or later. See:

- [Prevent explicit insert into serial columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116054/prevent-explicit-insert-into-serial-columns/116091#116091)

Related:

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)

---

Aside 1:
Use legal, **lower-case** names everywhere to avoid confusion. `SurveyWriter` will be created as `surveywriter`. I suggest `survey_writer` instead. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)

Aside 2:
Consider `timestamp with time zone`: `created_at timestamptz DEFAULT current_timestamp`. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: Wow.  Thank you so much for all the detailed help.  Most example code on postgres is too basic to be usable, and googling for this issue did not help me AT ALL.  I really appreciate the code review and advice.  You're a peach.